# Android app sends data to PHP script - Expectation failed

Tags: php, android

I try to develop an app which needs to send data to a MySql database.
In order to achieve it, I create a httppost as follows

```
public void postData() {    
     try {
       // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header 
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myscript.php");  
   // Add your data 
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Noon"));  
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("level", "0"));  
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

         // Execute HTTP Post Request  
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
         String text = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());          
            Log.i("","response = "+text); 
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
      e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {  
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
      e.printStackTrace();
     }  
 }
```

On my server, I have the following script:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password")
    or die("Impossible de se connecter : " . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected';

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Impossible de sélectionner la base de données : ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (name, level) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['name']."', '".$_REQUEST['level']."')");
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

The string text is filled with error 417 - expectation failed.

I understand the problem but does not understand how to fix it.
I would appreciate your help on this issue as I am a bit stuck.

Comment: I'd suggest using wireshark to see what the client is sending.  [HTTP 417](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E417.html) implies that the client is sending an `EXPECTS` header when it shouldn't be...

Answer (score 2):

You never put in the server URL. How is android supposed to know what to do with this

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myscript.php");
```

You should also format your code better.

Comment: If that's true, Android's error reporting sucks (using a HTTP 417 error? really)...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that I did put a right url in the HttpPost but I didn't want to show it as it's on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that I did put a right url in the HttpPost but I didn't want to show it as it's on the cloud. 
That's why I get a response from the script.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myscript.php");
httppost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think FAlmarri is right. you should put your complete url of your script in

```
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myscript.php");
```

you should use

> HttpPost httppost = new
>   HttpPost("**http://abc.com/folder path
>   of your script/myscript.php**");

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that I did put a right url in the HttpPost but I didn't want to show it as it's on the cloud.