# Android app sends data to PHP script - Expectation failed v2.0

Tags: php, android, http-post

Hello everyone and merry Christmas!

I have asked a question recently on StackOverflow: [Android app sends data to PHP script - Expectation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521757/android-app-sends-data-to-php-script-expectation-failed)

I didn't get the expected answer so I try another time with new clues.

First, I've found someone who gets the same error on this website: http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/doing-http-post-with-the-current-sdk-t5911-15.html

**---------------------------- Quote ------------------------------------------------**

Hi guys!
I need a little help.. I've tested every code on this forum and other websites, sanitizing them or using as written, but I always return the same error: 417 Expectation Failed.. I don't know anything about status error different from 404, 500, and so on..
Someone with more experience have a clue??
Thanks you a lot! If someone will find an answer I'll work hard for this forum with some open code!!

Chances are the reason why your code isn't working is because you don't understand how to build an HTTP request. The code is fine, your headers and content probably isn't!

Using a network protocol analyser (such as Wireshark), or FireBug or Chrome's built in development tools, read the POST requests you make to websites then rebuild them (using the same headers) in Android.

**---------------------------- UNQuote ------------------------------------------------**

I've tried to use wireshark and the results are when I don't use

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", "Noon"));  
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Level", "0"));  
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

the message sent is a httpPost

but when I use the nameValuePairs, no HttpPost is sent.

I am really lost with this error.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't a POST issue, it is a HttpClient-server issue... and you can solve it using a simple setting. An brief explanation of what is happening follows, but you can find more within `CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE` in the android documentation.

Before sending the contents of your entity through (i.e. the name-value pairs), the HttpClient is requesting that the server responds with a '100-continue' statement (the 'Expect: 100-continue' handshake). If the server fails to do this, its response comes back as a 417, and the entity isn't sent. You can stop the handshake though, by using the following lines when you initialise your HttpClient:

`mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();` 
`params = HttpClient.getParams();`
`params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE,false);`

That setting should stop your code from requesting the handshake, and the entity should be sent immediately.